# SharePoint 2010 - How to make a field Read-Only AFTER it loads

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a field that contains a number that is "system generated" when I open the Newform1.aspx form (I made this the default new item form).  If I make the "Requisition Number" field read only, it doesn't allow the system to write to it with the new number.  I would like the system to be able to write the new number to the field "as the form loads" and then make the field Read-Only after the number is generated and written to the field. Is there a way to make this happen?  When I just changed the ControlMode to "Display" it makes the field read only, but displays the Requisition Number from the first item in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how exactly you are adding this field.

1. If you have added the field using code or manifest, you can set field.ShowInEditForm = false;
2. If you are adding it using UI directly then there is no easy way to update ShowInEditForm property but there is one codeplex project which can help u

http://www.greggalipeau.com/2008/03/10/column-permissions-in-sharepoint-list/

tx,Sandeep

Comment: What that seemed to do is just set the field to Read Only.  I need the system to be able to create and write the new Requisition Number to the field as the form opens, but when the form is finished loading it needs to be Read Only and already have the new Requisition Number displayed in the field.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an event handler? You can use ItemAdding to update the field then set it to read only after the field is added.